# Correctly bundle HTMX with its extensions

Tags: javascript, bundle, package.json, htmx

I want to create one bundle with all the needed `htmx` extensions. But, every time I got this error after `npm run build` and view HTML page in browser:

```
response-targets.js:76 Uncaught ReferenceError: htmx is not defined
    at response-targets.js:76:5
    at response-targets.js:130:1
    at scripts.js:1:47137
```

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "project",
  "source": [
    "assets/scripts.js"
  ],
  "targets": {
    "default": {
      "distDir": "./static"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "htmx.org": "^1.9.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.11.0" // yes, I'm using Parcel 2 as bundler
  }
}
```

And my `./assets/scripts.js`:

```js
import 'htmx.org'
import 'htmx.org/dist/ext/response-targets.js'
// ... and other extensions ...
```